# Strange cross-domain issue with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am using the `iframe` below inside a different domain, however somehow the parent window is redirected both in Chrome and Firefox. Isn't this supposed to be blocked due to cross-domain policy?

I can block it by adding the `sandbox=""` attribute to the `iframe`, however I am still curious why this is possible.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.samplicio.us/router/default.aspx?SID=0db760c8-4858-4773-9e67-ca7e2cdb3cba&PID=7525e17a-a799-416c-bf84-4ea2e75ac332&AGE=24&GENDER=1&HISPANIC=1&ETHNICITY=1&STANDARD_HHI_US=3" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

While same-origin policy does block access to `Window` properties from cross-domain frames, the `location` property is a special exception.

From the [Cross-origin script API access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access) section of the MDN article on same-origin policy.

> JavaScript APIs such as `iframe.contentWindow`, `window.parent`, `window.open` and `window.opener` allow documents to directly reference each other. When the two documents do not have the same origin, these references provide very limited access to `Window` and `Location` objects, as described in the next two sections.

## Cross-Origin Window:

MDN lists the following methods and attributes or the `Window` object are permitted cross-origin, in accordance with [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#security-window).

#### Methods:

- `window.blur`
- `window.close`
- `window.focus`
- `window.postMessage`

#### Attributes:

- `window.closed` (read-only)
- `window.frames` (read-only)
- `window.length` (read-only)
- `window.location` (read/write)
- `window.opener` (read-only)
- `window.parent` (read-only)
- `window.self` (read-only)
- `window.top` (read-only)
- `window.window` (read-only)

## Cross-Origin Location:

Additionally, the following properties of the `Location` object are also permitted in accordance with [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#security-location).

#### Methods:

- `location.replace`

#### Attributes:

- `URLUtils.href` (write-only)

## In Summary:

As you can see above, `window.location` is read/write accessible across domains. Under same-origin policy, a frame is permitted to re-assign the `location` property of another frame. Use of the `sandbox` property would be the correct way to block such cross-origin frame access in modern browsers.

You might also be interested in reading the OWASP [Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet) page which has information on this technique of preventing a site from being framed, and some less-affective countermeasures that can be used in legacy browsers.